# div containers and alignment

Tags: css, html, css-float

this is my first time asking a question so please forgive me if I'm not asking the right questions. I'm having a problem with my website and I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in the divs and containers. I'm trying to keep the navigation at the top and I want to put some content underneath. The problem is the content isn't showing up. Also, I made a "spacer" id to push the text down where I wanted it. I'm not really sure how to align the text at the bottom without it. If anyone could help with that also, I would appreciate it.

I don't know which parts I should post so if it's any easier, I can just post the links to the page and the .css.

The page is:

http://www.preferredcaskets.com/Untitled.html

The CSS is:

http://preferredcaskets.com/nav.css

Again, forgive me if I'm not asking the right questions. It's late and I'm a little confused at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour and get to know how this site works. Format of your question does not fit the standards of this site. Post some code and show where exactly you think the problem is.

Comment: "Welcome to Preferred Caskets", if that is the content you would like to display? If so, try removing your image tag within the body and add it via css as background instead. This image is overlapping your contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put your background in an `<img>` tag, and given it `position:fixed`, which automatically places it on top of your other content. Quick fix: add `'style="z-index:-1;"` to the `<img>` tag. A Better way is to add it as a background to your body (and also more semantically correct, since the background is not part of your content).
css:

```
body{
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. I think the background is one of the reasons I'm getting confused. I've always set my background images the way you've just mentioned but I couldn't figure out how to get the background image to take up the full width of the screen. I ended up coming across a few tutorials on full width background earlier and ended up with what's on there now.

Comment: Try at CSS3 `background-size: cover`. Only works on newer browsers but is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try display inline in spacer

```
  #spacer {
   height:110px;
   width:auto;
   display:inline;

   }
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a4enG/